# In nixos, how to properly configure tmux?

Tags: tmux, nixos

In other distributons, I had the following tmux configuration in a file `~/.tmux.conf`.

```
# open new windows and panes in current directory
bind c new-window -c "#{pane_current_path}"
bind '"' split-window -c "#{pane_current_path}"
bind % split-window -h -c "#{pane_current_path}"

# do not wait for escape characters
set -s escape-time 0
```

This seems to work on nixos as well, but I am not sure whether this is the proper nixos way. By contrast, I noticed this popular github [tmux.nix configuration](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/nixos/modules/programs/tmux.nix).

**Is my method a proper nixos way to configure tmux?**

I'm wondering if using my `.tmux.conf` approach is consistent (or not) with nixos's principles of consistency, reproducability, declarativeness, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The NixOS configuration does not include user configuration, only system-wide configuration. The configuration you linked to generates `/etc/tmux.conf`, but not `~/.tmux.conf`.

Comment: Okay great I will keep my ~/.tmux then as my user-specific configuration.